# My number is associated with iMessage on other phone, how to remove it?

Tags: iphone, messages

Good day everyone. For only 1 hour (!) I used my relatives iPhone with my sim card and that's it, he keeps receiving all of my iMessages. I tried checking in iTunes all devices associated with my account and his device is not listed. I tried to log in and log out to/from iMessage on his phone with his apple ID, still won't help. How can I stop this nightmare!?
When I go to iMessage settings>Send & Receive on his device, there is only my phone number listed, how do I remove it without smashing phone to the wall?!
Thanks and have a great day

**EDIT.** After talking to apple support for some time, they removed my phone number from my friend's iMessage. So I guess if you are facing same problem you have to contact support.

Comment: Have him check his "Send and Receive Devices" and make sure your phone number is not listed.

Comment: That's exactly my question: "... When I go to iMessage settings>Send & Receive on his device, there is only my phone number listed, how do I remove it"..

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Does he have an email address listed, too?

Comment: We have logged in and out several times, ATM it's not listed

Comment: I just looked at my own iMessages "Send and Receive Devices," and my phone number is grayed out and cannot be removed. Are you experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Yea, actually talking to the Apple support right now, will post an update here

Comment: Did you try by chance to use Apple's Deregister iMessage service? https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions on Apple's [Deregister iMessage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage) should help you resolve this issue.