# How do I remove grayed out phone number in send/receive in message settings?

Tags: messages, iphone

My service has been disconnected on my iphone6. I want to use it for imessage, how do I remove the old phone number that's grayed out in the send/receive in message settings?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an (i) next to it?

Comment: No. There is a constant circle spinning next to the number.

Comment: Deregister the number in a web form http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246549/my-number-is-associated-with-imessage-on-other-phone-how-to-remove-it

Comment: @bmike his issue doesn't require filling out forms for a device that he no longer has. Only required step is to sign out/sign in. I've included the source in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### According to Apple, all you need to do is sign out of your device

[image] **Source:** https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
Check your iCloud preferences after signing out and back in.
*Settings › iCloud › User Account › Contact Information*

### If you are unable to remove/modify

Depending on your carrier, you may need to remove your sim and reinstall iOS.